# How to add to excel in date order

Tags: c#

I have to collect data from some Lotus messages and put them in the excel file. Data extracted from Lotus must be in date order. All is working fine, but I have this task that all of them must be in date order. The date I have now is a string (eg. 18.05.2013), and I guess I must use the string.Split('.') but after that, I don't know how to add in excel ordered. This is what I have now:

```
String subject = (string)((object[])doc.GetItemValue("Subject"))[0];

/* ------ get  number from mail ------ */
if (subject.Contains("DUNS:") && !DUNS.Contains(subject))
{
DUNS.Add(subject);
i++;
int k = 0;
int ss = subject.IndexOf(dunsStart) + dunsStart.Length;
string sub = subject.Substring(ss, dunsLenght);

String body = (string)((object[])doc.GetItemValue("Body"))[0];
Console.WriteLine(body);

/* ------ get due date from mail ------ */
int dds = body.IndexOf(dueDateStart) + dueDateStart.Length;
string bdy = body.Substring(dds, dueDateLenght);
bdy.Trim();
bdy = bdy.Replace("\r", String.Empty);
bdy = bdy.Replace("\n", String.Empty);
bdy = bdy.Replace("\t", String.Empty);
string[] date = bdy.Split(' ');
string dueDateWithoutDay = date[1];

/* ------ get usernames from mail ------ */

string stringA = usersStart;
string stringB = usersEnd;
int strStart = body.IndexOf(stringA) + stringA.Length;
int strEnd = body.IndexOf(stringB);
int strLenght = strEnd - strStart;
string line = body.Substring(strStart, strLenght);
line = line.Replace("\r", "^");
line = line.Replace("\n", "^");
line.Trim();
string[] lines = line.Split('^');
List<string> users = new List<string>();
foreach (string s in lines)
{
    if (s.Length > 1)
    {
        users.Add(s);
    }
}
try
{
    for (int n = 0; n < users.Count; n++)
    {
        if (users[n].Length > 0)
        {

            string[] foundedentrie = users[n].Split(' ');
            var userID = foundedentrie[0];
            var userName = foundedentrie[1] + foundedentrie[2];
            workSheet.Cells[i + 1, k + 1] = sub;
            workSheet.Cells[i + 1, k + 2] = dueDateWithoutDay;
            workSheet.Cells[i + 1, k + 3] = userID;
            workSheet.Cells[i + 1, k + 4] = userName;
            if (n < users.Count - 1)
            {
                i++;
            }
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: I'm confused. Are you wanting to rearrange your Users based on the due date?

Comment: I extracted the data from Lotus. The next thing I have to do is add data to Excel in descending order of dueDate. But dueDate is in dd.MM.yyyy format.